# Max value from list where true

Tags: excel, if-statement, max

i have a sheet that looks similar to this

```
 A       B       C
 2016    5       TRUE
 2015    7       FALSE
 2016    8       TRUE
 2016    3       TRUE
 2015    5       FALSE
```

I need to show the highest value of B and its A where C is TRUE.

So i guess i would need 2 formulas to show this.

I know that i should probably use MAX and IF however, i can't figure out how to put this together.

So in this example the result i want is:

```
2016
8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with this Array formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,IF((B:B=MAX(B:B))*(C:C),1,0),0))
```

[image]